# Element position and repetition syntax

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Please give me some advice.

There is box[x,y] and this is consisting of {{a1,{b1,c1},d,e},{a2,{b2,c2}}} elements.

For example, box[x] is list like this.(and Sometimes there is empty set)

```
box[x]=
{{{{9,{1,1},1,2},{10,{1,1}}},{{12,{4,2},1,2},{10,{1,1}}}},
{{{2,{1,3},1,2},{5,{2,1}}},{{11,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,1}}}},{{10,{4,2},2,3},{5,{1,2}}},{{9,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,2}}}},{}}
```

I break it down further.

```
box[1]={{{9,{1,1},1,2},{10,{1,1}}},{{12,{4,2},1,2},{10,{1,1}}}}
box[2]={{{2,{1,3},1,2},{5,{2,1}}},{{11,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,1}}}},{{10,{4,2},2,3},{5,{1,2}}}}
box[3]={{9,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,2}}}
box[4]={}
```

I would like to identify the elements and add words as follows.

[image]

So,I want to change their display as follows

```
box[1]={{{9,{1,1},1,2},{10,{1,1}},puls},{{12,{4,2},1,2},{10,{1,1}},minus}}}
box[2]={{{2,{1,3},1,2},{5,{2,1}},minus},{{11,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,1}},minus}},{{10,{4,2},2,3},{5,{1,2}},minus}}}
box[3]={{9,{2,2},1,1},{3,{2,2}},minus}}
box[4]={}
```

So I formulated the following equation.

```
Table[box[x] =
      If[Length@box[x] > 0,
       left = Part[box[x][[z, 1, 2]]];
       right = Part[box[x][[z, 2, 2]]];
       box[x] = Table[Append[box[x][[z]],
          If[left == right, StringJoin["puls"], "minus"]], {z,Length[box[x]]}], box[x] = {}], {x, 4}]
```

However,I got the error [expression "z" cannot be used for partial specification].
What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boxlist = {{{{9, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {1, 1}}}, {{12, {4, 2}, 1, 
     2}, {10, {1, 1}}}}, {{{2, {1, 3}, 1, 
     2}, {5, {2, 1}}}, {{11, {2, 2}, 1, 
     1}, {3, {2, 1}}}, {{10, {4, 2}, 2, 3}, {5, {1, 2}}}}, {{9, {2, 
     2}, 1, 1}, {3, {2, 2}}}, {}}

boxlist /. k : {{a1_, {b1_, c1_}, d_, e_}, {a2_, {b2_, c2_}}} :>  
  If[{b1, c1} == {b2, c2}, Append[k, "plus"], Append[k, "minus"]]
```

> {{{{9, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {1, 1}},     "plus"}, {{12, {4, 2}, 1, 2},
> {10, {1, 1}},     "minus"}}, {{{2, {1, 3}, 1, 2}, {5, {2, 1}},
> "minus"}, {{11, {2, 2}, 1, 1}, {3, {2, 1}},     "minus"}, {{10, {4,
> 2}, 2, 3}, {5, {1, 2}}, "minus"}}, {{9, {2, 2},
> 1, 1}, {3, {2, 2}}, "plus"}, {}}

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'd like to know what the "k" means.

Comment: Please visit the doc page for [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[appendPlusMinus]
appendPlusMinus = ReplaceAll[
   {a : {{_Integer, b : {_, _}, ___} ..} :> {a, "plus"}, 
    a : {{_Integer, {_, _}, ___} ..} :> {a, "minus"}}];
```

---

```
appendPlusMinus[box[#]] & /@ Range[4]

{  
 {{{{9, {1, 1}, 1, 2}, {10, {1, 1}}}, "plus"},   
  {{{12, {4, 2}, 1, 2}, {10, {1, 1}}}, "minus"}},    
 {{{{{2, {1, 3}, 1, 2}, {5, {2, 1}}}, "minus"},  
  {{{11, {2, 2}, 1, 1}, {3, {2, 1}}}, "minus"}},   
  {{{10, {4, 2}, 2, 3}, {5, {1, 2}}}, "minus"}},  
 {{{9, {2, 2}, 1, 1}, {3, {2, 2}}}, "plus"},   
 {}  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!